# body background-color vs html background-color

Tags: css

I wonder why if I won't specify `background-color` for `html`, the `background-color` specified for body will apply to whole page even though body `width` is set to only `200px`.

[image]

Comment: your question is true, but you should never set width to `body` ot html `tags`

Comment: @ma_dev_15 yes you are right as we don't have to set any width for body or html tags..

Comment: @Adrian Baran and this a common factor as you should be aware of it..